# javascript includes to check for multiple values existance

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

```
const colors = ["black", "red", "pink", ];
```

this is `colors` array.I can check if one of the values is present in colors array. For e.g. here, I want to check if  red is present in colors array. I use below code.

```
Const IsRedExist = colors.includes("red"); //returns true
```

So I want a flag to know if red or white or blue exists in colors array. How do I achieve that ? Any suggestions on this ?

Comment: another array with `some` or `every`

Comment: What do you mean by "want a flag"?

Answer (score 7):

So you some and every with another array. Solution depends on what you actually need.

```js
const colors = ["black", "red", "pink" ]

const checkFor = ["red", "white"]

const hasAll = checkFor.every(color => colors.includes(color))
const hasSome = checkFor.some(color => colors.includes(color))
const included = checkFor.filter(color => colors.includes(color))
const excluded = checkFor.filter(color => !colors.includes(color))
const checks = checkFor.reduce((obj, color) => ({[color]: colors.includes(color), ...obj}), {})

console.log('hasAll', hasAll)
console.log('hasSome', hasSome)
console.log('included', included)
console.log('excluded', excluded)
console.log('checks', checks, checks.red)
```